# How to get R to use a certain dataset for multiple commands without usin attach() or appending data="" to every command

Tags: r

So I'm trying to manipulate a simple Qualtrics CSV, and I want to use `colSums` on certain columns of data, *given a certain filter.*

For example: within the .csv file called `data`, I want to get the sum of a few columns, and print them with certain labels (say `choice1`, `choice2` etc). That is easy enough by itself:

```
firstqn<-data.frame(choice1=data$Q7_2,choice2=data$Q7_3,choice3=data$Q7_4);
secondqn<-data.frame(choice1=data$Q8_6,choice2=data$Q8_7,choice3=data$Q8_8)
print colSums(firstqn); print colSums(secondqn)
```

The problem comes when I want to repeat the above steps with different filters, - say, only the rows where `gender==2`.

The only way I know how is to create a new dataset `data2` and replace `data$` with `data2$` in every line of the above code, such as:

```
data2<-(data[data$Q2==2,])
firstqn<-data.frame(choice1=data2$Q7_2,choice2=data2$Q7_3,choice3=data2$Q7_4);
```

however i have 6 choices for each of 5 questions and am planning to apply about 5-10 different filters, and I don't relish the thought of copy/pasting `data2` and `data3' etc hundreds of times.

**So my question is: Is there any way of getting R to reference `data` by default without using `data$` in front of every variable name?**

I can probably use `attach()` to achieve this, but i really don't want to:

```
data2<-(data[data$Q2==2,])
attach(data2)
firstqn<-data.frame(choice1=Q7_2,choice2=Q7_3,choice3=Q7_4);
detach(data2)
```

is there a command like attach() that would allow me to avoid using `data$` in front of every variable, for a specified amount of code? Then whenever I wanted to create a new filter, I could just copy/paste the same code and change the first command (defining a new dataset).

I guess I'm looking for some command like `with(data2, *insert multiple commands here*)`

Alternatively, if anyone has a better way to do the above in an entirely different way please enlighten me - i'm not very proficient at R (yet).

Comment: you can use `with(data, commands)`.  Why didn't it work?  For multiple commands, you can use `{` inside `with` like `with(data, { command1; command2 })` where `;` is a line-break

Comment: Why don't you do `colSums(data[data$Q2==2, c("Q7_2", "Q7_3", "Q7_4")])`?

Comment: I wanted to add labels so that it's easier to tell which column the results are for. And @Richard Scriven can you do that with multiple commands? I was under the impression that with() works one command at a time. Do you just use with(data, command1;command2;command3)?

Comment: @squazee You can do it with only one command at a time, but it mostly looks like what you need can be done in one command (see Roland's comment)

Comment: If you wait some time I'm sure a disciple of hadley will come along and show you how to use pipes.

Comment: In any case, it looks like what you actually want is more like a `group_by` statement. If you reorganize your data to melt it into tidy data (one row per question-choice combination, instead of one row per question), you'll have a much easier time working with it. See [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html)

Comment: Or, in general, right a function that takes a `data` argument and does what you want. Then you just call that function on whatever subsets of your data that you'd like.

Comment: @Roland The dog in my avatar is an expert with pipes. Maybe we should ask him for some help.